# Submit form using AJAX and <a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've been trying to get this to work but unable to.
All my forms normally have `submit input` on them and I process AJAX submission like below;

```
<script>
$("input#submit").click(function () {
    $("#login-form").submit(function (e) {
        $('#loader').show();
        // Client side validation
        if ($("#email").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "") {
            $('#loader').hide();
            fieldError();
        } else {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                success: function (response) {
                    switch (response) {
                    case "Valid":
                        $('#loader').hide();
                        $('#login-form').trigger("reset");
                        window.location.href = "index.php";
                        break;
                    case "not eValid":
                        $('#loader').hide();
                        emailError();
                        break;
                    case "not Valid":
                        $('#loader').hide();
                        credError();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind();
    });
});
</script>
```

Now I want to achieve the same thing using an  tag. Below is my code that doesn't work;

```
<script>
$("a.update").click(function () {
    $("#address-form").submit(function (e) {
        $('#loader').show();
        // Client side validation
        if ($("#addressLine1").val() == "" || $("#addressLine2").val() == "" || $("#addressLine3").val() == "") {
            $('#loader').hide();
            fieldError();
        } else {
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                success: function (response) {
                    switch (response) {
                    case "Valid":
                        $('#loader').hide();
                        $('#address-form').trigger("reset");
                        //window.location.href="index.php";
                        break;
                    case "not Valid":
                        $('#loader').hide();
                        credError();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind();
    });
});
</script>
```

No error provided in Chrome console.
Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Error what is the error

Comment: Nothing is posted in Chrome console

Comment: put e.preventDefault(); // on a tag onclick

Comment: You're adding a `submit` handler on each click of the link instead of submitting the form.

Comment: In practice don't use anchor tag or submit buttons for sending ajax, use button or label.

Answer (score 0):

use document ready &

```
 $("a.update").click(function (e) {

        $('#loader').show();
        // Client side validation
        if ($("#addressLine1").val() == "" || $("#addressLine2").val() == "" || $("#addressLine3").val() == "") {
            $('#loader').hide();
            fieldError();
        } else {

            var postData = $("#address-form").serializeArray();
            var formURL = $("#address-form").attr("action");

            $.ajax({
                url: formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                success: function (response) {
                    switch (response) {
                        case "Valid":
                            $('#loader').hide();
                            $('#address-form').trigger("reset");
                            //window.location.href="index.php";
                            break;
                        case "not Valid":
                            $('#loader').hide();
                            credError();
                            break;
                    }
                }


            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind();
        });
```

Comment: Should the <a> have a href?

Comment: to properly validate the html it has to have you can do a hash as a url `<a href="#">submit</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong:

```
$("a.update").click(function () {
    $("#address-form").submit(function (e) {

        $('#loader').show();
        // Client side validation
        // etc.
```

When the link is clicked, you bind the an action to the submit event to your form. That is not what you want; you probably want to trigger the submit action code when the link is clicked.

Apart from that you are not cancelling the default click action of the link so it will be followed.

You only need:

```
$("a.update").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#loader').show();
    // Client side validation
    // etc.
```

**Edit:** Good point by @Andreas, you need to address your form correctly in the modified code:

```
        var postData = $("#address-form").serializeArray();
        var formURL = $("#address-form").attr("action");
```

Comment: And the two calls with `$(this)...` in the `else` branch have to be changed accordingly